# My Login component flashes whenever I reload my dashboard

Tags: reactjs

I'm using reactjs to build a login/register system with authentication and authorization. if authenticated(jsonwebtoken), it should route me to the dashboard else redirect me back to login.
but whenever I reload it hits the login endpoint for a second then back to dashboard. how can I fix this?

Below is a giphy to show what I'm talking about

[image]

> **Here are the components associated with the issue stated above**
> App.js

```
const App = () => {

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)
 
  // set isAuthenticated to true or false
  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // check if the person is still Authenticated
    const isAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch('/auth/verify', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { token: localStorage.token},
        })
        const data = await res.json()
       // if authenticated, then
       if(data === true) {
        await setIsAuthenticated(true)
       } else {
        await setIsAuthenticated(false)
       }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
      }
    }
    isAuth()
  })
  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <div className='container'>
            <Switch>
  
              <Route exact path='/login' render={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Login {...props} setAuth={setAuth} /> : <Redirect to='/dashboard' /> } />
  
              <Route exact path='/register' render={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Register {...props} setAuth={setAuth} /> : <Redirect to='/login' />} />
              
              <Route exact path='/dashboard' render={props => isAuthenticated  ? <Dashboard {...props} setAuth={setAuth} /> : <Redirect to='/login' /> } />
  
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Fragment>
    );
```

> **Login Component**

```
const Login = ({ setAuth }) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    })

    const { email, password } = text

    const onChange = e => setText({ ...text, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            // Get the body data
            const body = { email, password }
            const res = await fetch('/auth/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            })
            const data = await res.json()
            if(data.token) {
                 // save token to local storage
                localStorage.setItem("token", data.token)
                setAuth(true)
                toast.success('Login Successful')
            } else {
                setAuth(false)
                toast.error(data)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
        }
        
    }
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className='text-center my-5'>Login</h1>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
```

> **Dashboard Component**

```
const Dashboard = ({ setAuth }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const getName = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('/dashboard', {
                    method: 'GET', 
                    // Get the token in localStorage into the header
                    headers: { token: localStorage.token }
                })
                const data = await res.json()

                setName(data.user_name)

            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err.message)
            }
        }
        getName()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    // Log out 
    const logOut = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.removeItem("token")
        setAuth(false)
        toast.success('Logged Out')
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className='mt-5'>Dashboard</h1>
            <p>Hello, {name}</p>
            <button className='btn btn-primary my-3' onClick={e => logOut(e)}>Log Out</button>
        </Fragment>
```

Comment: You don't really need `setAuth` (can be replaced with `setIsAuthenticated`) and checking localStorage doesn't need to happen async. In your code you're fetching `/auth/verify` on every refresh. That will take time hence the flash. You can set this once and just check for the localStorage instead. Remember to not rely on localStorage for auth or any other client side code for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that I found in your code above.

The first is that your ueEffect does not specify any dependency.
When the dependencies are not specified in this way the useEffect would run anytime any state changes.

```
useEffect(()=> {
 // code here
}); // this one would run anytime any state changes in the component. You usually don't want this.
```

When a dependency array is specified, the code in the useEffect would run anytime any of the state in the dependencies changes.

```
useEffect(()=> {
 // code here
},
[state1, state2, ...others...] //code would run when any of the state in this array changes
```

In your case, however, you probably want to run that useEffect once. To do this we add an empty array as the dependency value.

```
useEffect(()=> {
 // code here
},
[] //empty deps means that the code runs only once. When the component mounts
)
```

**Extra ideas**

I also suggest that you add a loading state to your component so that you can show a loader while the API call is being made.

You might want to show a loader while the API call is being made(or even set this state to true by default since the API call is the first thing you do in your app)
.

Also, consider putting useEffect in a custom Hook